# How to use ocra to pack script using fxruby gem into executable?

Tags: ruby, ocra, fxruby

I'm new to ruby and I'm trying to use ocra to pack a script that uses the fxruby gem to create a GUI, however, my command creates an executable that doesn't perform any action, this is the command I'm using:

`ocra --no-enc --no-dep-run --gem-full --add-all-core table.rbw`

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've searched the internet but couldn't find any useful info, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to generate an *.exe for Windows?

I have some scripts that also use FX and they run nicely on Windows.

This is how I generate the file:

```
ocra MyScript.rb --gem-all --windows
```

You can also try

```
ocra --help
```

And this will display all the parameters available.